# How can i run the existing Django project in my mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to run the Django project in my machine and i have cloned it. Now i directly run the the Project by
`python3 manage.py runserver`and after that i got the error like this

```
192:vehiclerent vishal$ python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1052, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 989, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1318, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mathfilters'
```

Can anyone help how can i resolve this and explain what's happening.

Comment: Install your projects requirements... Your project is using certain packages which you don't seem to have installed.

Comment: How can i find that what packages i need to install, can you tell ?

Comment: First check if you have a requirements.txt file. If yes then you can run

"pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt"

Comment: No, actually i don't have the file.

Is there any other way ?

Comment: This is not even issue releated to macOS, but anyway I use macs since 2016 and everything works fine (I develop Django stuff on daily basis). Try to find package on pypi and install it via pip...

Comment: I resolved this but there is one thing that i got this error 
```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```
ig i need to install mysql first ?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t just clone a project and get on using it. That project might have a requirements.txt file. In your active virtual environment, cd into the directory that contains your requirements.txt and run the command `pip install -r requirements.txt` in your terminal. This will install all the packages listed in your requirements.txt file.

If no requirements.txt file exists, then you can search for the packages to be installed on PyPi and follow the instructions for installation. Pay attention to the version of the package to be installed.